# Request in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I'm new to Laravel and making an API. In my project, data validation using the queries I created does not work. When I try, for example, to create a user with empty fields, I get the main page with the status 200. Please tell me how I can fix this error. I'll show you the route api.php and one of the controllers where the request I created is applied.

**AuthController:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\UserCreateRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\UserLoginRequest;
use Egulias\EmailValidator\Exception\AtextAfterCFWS;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use phpDocumentor\Reflection\DocBlock\Tags\Uses;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function store(UserCreateRequest $request){
        $user               = new User();
        $user->login        = $request->get('login');
        $user->password     = Hash::make($request->get('password'));
        $user->fio          = $request->get('fio');
        $user->email        = $request->get('email');
        $user->number_phone = $request->get('number_phone');
        $user->assignRole('user');

        if (!$user->save()) {
            return response()->json(['message'=>'Регистрация не удалась'], 422);
        }

        return response()->json(['message'=> 'Регистрация прошла успешно'], 200);
    }

    public function login(UserLoginRequest $request){

        $user = User::query()->where('login', $request->get('login'))->first();
        if (!$user || !Hash::check($request->get('password'), $user->password)) {
            return response()->json(['message'=>'Попытка входа не удалась'], 422);
        }

        $token = $user->createToken('api_token')->plainTextToken;
        $user->api_token = $token;
        $user->save();
        $user = Auth::login($user);

        return response()->json(['message'=>Auth::user()->api_token], 200);
    }

    public function logout(Request $request) {
        $request->user()->currentAccessToken()->delete();

        return response()->json(['message' => 'Вы вышли из системы'], 200);
    }
}
```

**UserCreateRequest:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class UserCreateRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'login'                 => 'required|string|unique:user,login',
            'password'              => 'required|string|min:8|max:30',
            'fio'                   => 'required|string',
            'email'                 => 'required|email|string',
            'number_phone'          => 'required|string|min:10'
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
          'login.required'          => 'Поле "Логин" обязательно',
          'login.string'            => 'Поле "Логин" должно содержать только буквы и цифры',
          'login.unique:user,login' => 'Логин должен быть уникальным',

          'password.required'       => 'Поле "Пароль" обязательно',
          'password.string'         => 'Поле "Пароль" должно содержать только буквы и цифры',
          'password.min:8'          => 'Поле "Пароль" должно содержать не менее 8 символов',
          'password.max:30'         => 'Поле "Пароль" должно содержать не более 30 символов',

          'fio.required'            => 'Поле "ФИО пользователя" обязательно',
          'fio.sring'               => 'Поле "ФИО пользователя" должно содержать только буквы и цифры',

          'email.required'          => 'Поле "Email" обязательно',
          'email.email'             => 'Поле "Email" должно соответствовать своему типу',
          'email.string'            => 'Поле "Email" должно содержать только буквы и цифры',

          'number_phone.required'   => 'Поле "Номер телефона" обязательно',
          'number_phone.string'     => 'Поле "Номер телефона" должно содержать только буквы и цифры',
          'number_phone.min:10'     => 'Поле "Номер телефона" должно содержать не менее 10 символов',
        ];
    }
}
```

**api.php**

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\ApplicationController;
use App\Http\Controllers\AuthController;
use App\Http\Controllers\ReviewController;
use App\Http\Controllers\AdminController;
use App\Http\Requests\UserLoginRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:admin']], function () {
    Route::get('user', [AdminController::class, 'show'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');
    Route::post('userUpdate/{user}', [AdminController::class, 'update'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');
    Route::post('userStore', [AdminController::class, 'store'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');
    Route::post('userDelete/{user}', [AdminController::class, 'delete'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');
    Route::post('applicationUpdate/{application}', [AdminController::class, 'updateStatus'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');
    Route::post('applicationDeleteAdmin/{application}', [AdminController::class, 'deleteApplication'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');
});

Route::post('login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);
Route::post('authStore', [AuthController::class, 'store']);
Route::get('authLogout', [AuthController::class, 'logout'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');

Route::get('application', [ApplicationController::class, 'show'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');
Route::post('applicationStore', [ApplicationController::class, 'store'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');
Route::post('applicationDelete/{application}', [ApplicationController::class, 'delete'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');

Route::get('review', [ReviewController::class, 'showReview']);
Route::post('reviewStore', [ReviewController::class, 'store'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');
Route::post('reviewDelete/{review}', [ReviewController::class, 'deleteReview'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');
Route::post('reviewUpdate/{id}', [ReviewController::class, 'updateReview'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');

Route::post('reviewRatingStore/{review}', [ReviewController::class, 'storeEstimation'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');
Route::post('reviewRatingDelete/{reviewRating}', [ReviewController::class, 'deleteEstimation'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');
Route::get('reviewRating', [ReviewController::class, 'showReviewRating']);
```

**User.php**

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;

/**
 * @property integer $id Идентификатор
 * @property string $login Логин пользователя
 * @property string $password Пароль пользователя
 * @property string $fio ФИО пользователя
 * @property string $email Email пользователя
 * @property string $number_phone Номер телефона пользователя
 * @property string $api_token Токен пользователя
 * @property integer $role_id Роль пользователя
 */

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable, HasApiTokens, HasRoles;

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $table = 'user';

    protected $hidden = ['password', 'role_id'];

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */

    protected $fillable = [
        'login',
        'password',
        'fio',
        'email',
        'number_phone',
        'api_token',
        'role_id'
    ];

    public function application(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Model\Application');
    }

    public function review(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Model\Review');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your

```
$request->get('login')
```

to

```
$request->input('login')
```

or this

```
$request->login
```

[Request Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests)
[Validation Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation)

Comment: Попробовал `$request->input('login')` и `$request->login`. It didn't help

Comment: Also, what's the result of **dd($request->all())**, put this at the first line of store function

Comment: I can't edit my answer yet. It says that the suggested editing queue is full. I tried dd ($request->all ()). The result is the same. If the User Create Request is changed to Request, then I get the data from the form